# Capybara. Is it possible to add annotation not in the start but in the middle of Scenario?

Tags: annotations, capybara, sidekiq

I have a stub that starting and stopping sidekiq, when I add it before Scenario it does not allow perform another functionality witch is started in the very beginning of Scenario. May be anybody know how to put such type of annotations in the middle of the Scenario?

I meant  that I use annotation before Scenario, for instance:

```
@chrome @sidekiqstab

Feature: I am login as Doctor 1

Background:
Given I am a registered doctor

And I have name set to 'Doctor1'

Scenario: User make some action.

Given I am log in

And I am creating patient with { name: 'Glory' }

When I am log in as Doctor1

And I am opening /
```

And so on .....

Is it exist any ways to put @sidekiqstab for instance after "And I am opening /....

This part of steps I mentioned is just for example

Comment: Give more details - example code, etc -- See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No, there is no way to add cucumber tags in the middle of a scenario (although a step can do anything a tag would do).  It's also not clear how adding the @sidekiqstab tag would prevent anything else from running, so it would help if you provide actual real details, the code handling the tags,  and the specific error you're getting.